# JVM running out of memory in Bamboo

Tags: amazon-ec2, bamboo

I'm facing an issue.

Currently running a build, in On-Demand Bamboo server in AWS, I'm getting an error and the log says:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory.......failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)      

# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.  
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map XXXXX bytes for committing reserved memory."
```

Does anyone know how can I allocate memory to Bamboo, since is hosted in AWS? (I do not have much experience with both)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever solve this?  I would start by checking the memory usage (**free -m**) and then try running the build outside of Bamboo, to see if that work as expected.

You can also update the setenv.sh file in the bamboo bin directory to add memory options.  Update the JAVA_OPTS with some reasonable values, e.g. -Xmx768m -Xms512m, that makes sense for your build projects.

Comment: Since it is an account I have for minor tests, the workaround was rebooting EC2.